# What happens during execution of JAL 0x00400070

Tags: assembly, mips

Basically, I'm trying to describe in words what happens when JAL 0x00400070 executes. Looking up some jal examples online I found this
"Very Tricky: the middle step of the machine cycle has already incremented the PC by four. At this point the PC holds the address of the instruction just after the jal instruction. Now the execute phase of the jal instruction adds four to that address and puts the result in $ra. So now $ra holds the address of the second instruction after the jal instruction."

My main confusion comes from the fact that during the machine cycle it already incremented the PC by four. Do I account for this as part of the execution or is this a different step?

If I don't account for this, I would get that the jal instruction would add four to JAL 0x00400070 + 4 = 0x00400074 and this is placed in $ra. Do I need to say anything more about the PC here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That is part of normal execution, since `PC` needs to advance to next instruction. For architectures with fixed length instructions such as MIPS, I guess it's part of the fetch, otherwise it's probably part of decode. Note that it's **not** `0x00400070 + 4` that is placed in `$ra` since in your example `0x00400070` is the target address and not the current `PC`.

Comment: @Jester jal sub    # $ra <― PC+4  (the address 8 bytes away from the jal) 
           # PC  <― sub   load the PC with the subroutine entry point
           # a branch delay slot follows this instruction This was a part of the example which then really confuses me as you say it is not the target +4. So would it be the target + 8 since it is supposed to be 8 bytes away from the jal?

Comment: No, not the target. The return address is the address of `JAL` itself + 8.